Need advice on feature engineering on Longitudinal Data
I'm trying to predict the rated capacity of a wind turbine given factors such as wind speed and direction. Now since this is weather data which is high resolution, I don't want to just average things like wind speed, direction, and temperature over a timespan. The way I'm envisioning the data is that each turbine has associated timeseries data of certain variables over a time. I'm currently stuck on how I should approach characterizing the timeseries without being too reductive(such as averaging and variance).
An idea that I had was to take each series for each turbine and put it into bins, so lets say for the temperature series I'd have bins for ranges of temperature and track the frequencies of each range for each turbine. Would this be a good idea? What other methods should I look at to transform the data so that its suitable for a prediction model?
